# Variably typecasting strings to Enums in PHP

Tags: php, enums, casting

Suppose I've got two Backed Enums:

```
enum Colors: string
{
    case Blue = "blue";
    case Red = "red";
}

enum Fruits: string
{
    case Apple = "apple";
    case Pear = "pear";
}
```

In my actual Yii2 implementation, I'd like to typecast variable object attributes to attribute type. In the database I store values as strings like "blue" and "apple" which I'd like to cast to enums. In the variable initialization of my custom so called 'Yii2 Behavior', I pass multiple parameters along like `[color => Colors::class, fruit => Fruit::class]`, telling the behavior which Enum to parse certain attributes to. At that point the Behavior doesn't know anything of the actual values yet.

In the 'Behavior', a function ends up with `$value` and `$type`, where for example `$value === "blue"` and `$type === "Namespace\Colors"` (which is the result of `Colors::class`). I'd like this function to return `enum Namespace\Colors::Blue`.

I've tried

```
if($type instanceof \BackedEnum) {
    return $type::from($value);
}
```

which obviously fails as $type is just a string.

So I tried

```
if((new ($type)) instanceof \BackedEnum) {
    return $type::from($value);
}
```

which fails on `Cannot instantiate enum 'Namespace\Colors'`.

I'm stuck on this, does anyone have any idea how to solve this situation? What can I pass along or process differently to variably typecast a string to an Enum? Many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code, because `$type` is a string, you cannot call a method on a string, you need some function like `call_user_func` to run it.

```
call_user_func([$type, 'from'], $value);
```